# How to write recursion without using class field in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have the following correct Java code to find the in-order `k`th element in a binary tree.

```
private static int count = 0;
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k) {
    count=0;
    return findkthInOrder(root, k, 0);
}
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k,int a) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;
    T rt = findkthInOrder(root.left, k, 0);
    if (rt != null)
        return rt;
    count++;
    if (count == k) {
        return root.data;
    }
    return findkthInOrder(root.right, k, 0);
}
```

But I really want to remove the use of `count`, possibly by making use of an additional method argument. I also want to keep it as recursion, and require the method `findkthInOrder` to return `T` type value.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: is this homework?  it looks like your professor left a clue for your in the code.

Comment: @jdigital: no, it is not homework. It is something I practice on my own. Please tell me your observation.

Comment: the hint: what is the parameter `a` ?

Comment: @jdigital: I wrote the code myself. `a` was supposed to be a dummy just to distinguish the two overloaded methods. I have thought about it already, but did not get any further. please help by giving the working code.

Comment: why do you use the 'a' parameter if it's allways set to 0?

Comment: Why insist on returning T from the helper method? It's a helper method.  If that's truly a requirement, perhaps `Node< T >` should maintain count information about its subtree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is overkill but here goes...The only mutable number class I could find in Java was `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`

```
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k) {
    return findkthInOrder(root, k, new AtomicInteger(0));
}
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k, AtomicInteger count) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;
    T rt = findkthInOrder(root.left, k, count);
    if (rt != null)
        return rt;
    if (count.incrementAndGet() == k) {
        return root.data;
    }
    return findkthInOrder(root.right, k, count);
}
```

I had made premature optimization, fixed now.

Here is alternate solution:

```
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k) {
    return findkthInOrder(root, k, new int[]{0});
}
public static <T> T findkthInOrder(Node<T> root, int k, int[] count) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;
    T rt = findkthInOrder(root.left, k, count);
    if (rt != null)
        return rt;
    count[0]++;
    if (count[0] == k) {
        return root.data;
    }
    return findkthInOrder(root.right, k, count);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is indeed an overkill to use AtomicInteger. I guess I will have to use some non-immutable counter as method argument to make it work, is it true? Simple `int count` as argument will not make it work EVER?

Comment: That's correct. Another solution is to change `new AtomicInteger(0)` to `new int[]{0}`... You get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the count value in an object (`Integer` is not useful as it is inmutable).

Add a method `add(int)` to increase the count; another one to get current value.

Pass the object recursively.

Comment: You need to know how many items the recursive calls are passing. Either you do it this way, or the tree structure provides you a way of knowing how many nodes a subtree has, or you modify your return parameter in order to return the number of evaluated nodes together with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Node< T > {
    T tData;
    Node< T > ntLeft, ntRight;
    int iSubtreeCount;
    public Node( T tData, Node< T > ntLeft, Node< T > ntRight ) {
        this.tData = tData;
        this.ntLeft = ntLeft;
        this.ntRight = ntRight;
        this.iSubtreeCount = subCount( ntLeft ) + subCount( ntRight ) + 1;
    }
    public static int subCount( Node< T > nt ) {
        return null == nt ? 0 : nt.getSubtreeCount();
    }
    public int getSubtreeCount() { return iSubtreeCount; }
    public Node< T > getLeft() { return ntLeft; }
    public Node< T > getRight() { return ntRight; }
    public T getData() { return tData; }
}
```

And your routine:

```
public static < T > T findKth( Node< T > ntInput, int k ) {
    if ( 0 == k || null == ntInput )
        return null;
    else if ( Node.subCount( ntInput.getLeft() ) > k - 1 )
        return findKth( ntInput.getLeft(), k );
    else if ( Node.subCount( ntInput.getLeft() ) == k - 1 )
        return ntInput.getData();
    else
        return findKth( ntInput.getRight(), k - 1 - Node.subCount( ntInput.getLeft() ) );
}
```